# Match pattern in Ruby with Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

Lets say we have the following array of strings (this array is a lot bigger):

```
[
  'http://www.example.com?id=123456',
  'http://www.example.com?id=234567'
]
```

As you can see, everything up to the first digit is the same in both strings. Is there a way to easily find what both strings have in common and what is different? So that I get a string like `'http://www.example.com?id='` and and array like `['123456', '234567']`.

Comment: What should happen for `['http://www.example.com?id=123456', 'http://www.example.com?id=123457']`?

Comment: Regexp might not be the ideal tool for this.  Building a trie is straightforward, not horribly slow, and solves your problem.

Comment: It should output (as said in the question) 'http://www.example.com?id=', since both strings have it in common.

Comment: @Taemyr Could you give an example of how you would do that?

Comment: @Severin Never programmed in Ruby.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042426/explanation-of-ruby-code-for-building-trie-data-structures discussed it, but the answer invokes commands that I am not familiar with so I can't vouch for it's function.  Trie's are a common data structure so it's fairly googleable. - Also note that it's a bit of an overkill for your problem.

Comment: @BroiSatse For your example it should output 'http://www.example.com?id=12345'

Comment: Post any Ruby/Regex you've `trie`d so far

Comment: You can reuse my solution from this quotestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406102/longest-common-prefix-and-suffix-of-arrays. It was for an array, ut should work for strings as well

Comment: Don't you want to parse the URL first? Multiple URL parameters (the key/value pairs after the `?`) can be in any order. Or do you not want to apply any URL logic here and use a strict substring comparison?

Comment: Simple string comparison will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method to find the longest common prefix in an array.

```
def _lcp(str1, str2)
  end_index = [str1.length, str2.length].min - 1
  end_index.downto(0) do |i|
    return str1[0..i] if str1[0..i] == str2[0..i]
  end
  ''
end

def lcp(strings)
  strings.inject do |acc, str|
    _lcp(acc, str)
  end
end


lcp [
  'http://www.example.com?id=123456',
  'http://www.example.com?id=234567',
  'http://www.example.com?id=987654'
]
#=> "http://www.example.com?id="

lcp [
  'http://www.example.com?id=123456',
  'http://www.example.com?id=123457'
]
#=> "http://www.example.com?id=12345"
```

Comment: Edit: changed `max` to `min`, because the longest prefix can only be as long as the shorter one of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This is an approach using higher level ruby std-lib components instead of a regex.
# Why re-invent the wheel?
module UriHelper
    require 'uri'
    require 'cgi'

    # Take an array of urls and extract the id parameter.
    # @param urls {Array} an array of urls to parse
    # @returns {Array}
    def UriHelper.get_id_params( urls )
        urls.map do |u| 
            puts u
            uri = URI(u)
            params = CGI::parse(uri.query)  
            params["id"].first # returned
        end
    end
end

require "test/unit"
# This is unit test proving our helper works as intended
class TestUriHelper < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_get_id_params
    urls = [
        'http://www.example.com?id=123456',
        'http://www.example.com?id=234567'
    ]
    assert_equal("123456", UriHelper.get_id_params(urls).first )
    assert_equal("234567", UriHelper.get_id_params(urls).last )
  end
end
```